# Error when populating data with foreign keys - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a migration from Entity Framework Core. When I try to add data, I get the following error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'ProductInStock' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Product' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'ProductInStock' and specify the foreign key values {'ProductId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Sorry for my English.

My classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Descripcion { get; set; } = null!;
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductInStock> ProductInStocks { get; set; } = new List<ProductInStock>();
}

public class ProductInStock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } = new();
}
```

This is the class configuration

```
public class ProductConfiguration
{
    public ProductConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> entityBuilder) 
    {
        entityBuilder.ToTable("Product");

        entityBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        entityBuilder.Property(x => x.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(100)
            .IsRequired();

        entityBuilder.Property(x => x.Descripcion)
            .HasMaxLength(500)
            .IsRequired();                       
    }
}

public class ProductInStockConfiguration
{
    public ProductInStockConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductInStock> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.ToTable("ProductInStock");

        entityBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        entityBuilder.Property(x => x.ProductId)
            .IsRequired();

        entityBuilder.Property(x => x.Stock)
            .HasPrecision(20, 6)
            .IsRequired();

        entityBuilder
            .HasOne(e => e.Product)
            .WithMany(e => e.ProductInStocks)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Product_stock")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Here are the methods to seed some data:

```
public static class ProductSeedData
{
    public static void PopulateProduct(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        var ramdom = new Random();

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<Product>()
           .HasData(Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
               .Select(index => new Product()
               {
                   Id = index,
                   Name = $"Producto {index}",
                   Descripcion = $"Descripcion para el producto {index}",
                   Price = ramdom.Next(100, 1000),
               }));
    }
}

public static class ProductInStockSeedData
{
    public static void PopulateProductInStock(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var productInStocks = new List<ProductInStock>();
        var ramdom = new Random();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ProductInStock>()
            .HasData(Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                .Select(index => new ProductInStock()
                {
                    Id = index,
                    ProductId = index,
                    Stock = ramdom.Next(0, 100),
                }));
    }
}

public static class ModelBuilderExtension
{
    public static void SeedData(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.PopulateProduct();
        modelBuilder.PopulateProductInStock();
    }
}
```

My context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductInStock> Stocks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Constants.m_DefaultSchema);

        ModelConfig(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.SeedData();
    }

    private static void ModelConfig(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _ = new ProductConfiguration(modelBuilder.Entity<Product>());
        _ = new ProductInStockConfiguration(modelBuilder.Entity<ProductInStock>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProductInStock` class, consider removing the `new` keyword for Navigation property `Product`

```
public class ProductInStock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; };
}
```

Please try and let me know if it work.

Thanks

Comment: Hello! this works for me. Thanks